# Swift 3: Rerecord video through AVFoundation

Tags: ios, camera, swift3, avfoundation, xcode8

I am  Record video through custom camera successfully but one thing more. when i want to again record video then nothing happen. How i fix this.  I am loading `cameraConfigration()` method in `viewWillAppear()` and for Start Recording call `recordVideo()` method and for stop call `Stoprecording()` method.  Here is my code.

```html
func stopRecording() {
        sessionOutput.stopRecording()
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        
    }
    func recordVideo(){
        // custom camera
        let paths = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let outputFile = paths.appending("t\(Timestamp).MOV")
        let outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:outputFile)
        
        sessionOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputURL as URL!, recordingDelegate: self)
    }
func cameraConfigration(){
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)
        for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back){
                do{
                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                    if(captureSession.canAddInput(input)){
                        captureSession.addInput(input);
                        
                        if(captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput)){
                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput);
                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait;
                            cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);
                            
                        }
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print("exception!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func startCameraFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController, withDelegate delegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate) -> Bool {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) == false {
            return false
        }
        let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraController.sourceType = .camera
        cameraController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String]
        cameraController.allowsEditing = false
        cameraController.delegate = delegate
        
        present(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return true
    }
```

```html
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        cameraConfigration()
    }
```

``

Comment: if your question is answered, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `stopRecording()` function, in this function you stop the recording and remove `previewLayer` form its superview `previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()` and again when you try to start the recording `previewLayer` is missing, the controller cannot find the `previewLayer` so nothing is happening.

try commenting the line `previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()` or add you `previewLayer` in `startRecording()` function.

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait;
cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);
```

before start Recording. `sessionOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputURL as URL!, recordingDelegate: self)`
 before this line.